# How to prevent jekyll code running within markdown code blocks

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I was trying to add the following codes in a markdown code block on a Jekyll blog. However, the code within braces {% %} cannot be displayed.

```
{% for post in site.categories.[page.category] %}
{% if year != nyear %}
<p>{{ year }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Anybody know how to prevent the codes within {% %} running? (I'm using `markdown: kramdown` in my `_config.yml` file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the raw tag.

```
{% raw %}
{% for post in site.categories.[page.category] %}
{% if year != nyear %}
<p>{{ year }}</p>
{% endif %}
...
{% endraw %}
```

This will render the liquid code as is.